# ¿Cómo romper una cadena de un número para poner cada uno de sus dígitos en una columna de un dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo un marco de datos en el que algunas filas son como escalas. Sin embargo, algunas de ellas fueron reagrupadas para formar números que permanecen en una columna en lugar de tener cada número en una columna "Answeri", y que varían desde el 0 hasta el número máximo de respuestas (número en nuestro caso):

```
>>> data[data.QType=='Likert Scale'].iloc[:,:20].drop(['QType'], axis=1)
Questions   Answers     Answer0     Answer1     Answer2     Answer3     Answer4     Answer5     Answer6     Answer7     Answer8     Answer9     Answer10    Answer11
3   What is your preference for a in-hotel grocery...   ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ...   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  NaN     NaN
55  Were you financially impacted due to the COVID...   ['12345']   12345   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
78  3 - If yes, on a scale of 0 -10, to what exten...   ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ...   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  NaN     NaN
```

Quiero algo como:

```
Questions   Answers     Answer0     Answer1     Answer2     Answer3     Answer4     Answer5     Answer6     Answer7     Answer8     Answer9     Answer10    Answer11
3   What is your preference for a in-hotel grocery...   ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ...   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  NaN     NaN
55  Were you financially impacted due to the COVID...   ['12345']   1   2     3     4      5    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
78  3 - If yes, on a scale of 0 -10, to what exten...   ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ...   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  NaN     NaN
```

Intenté hacerlo con "enumerar" y usar el contador "fusionar" con "responder" para poner en la columna buena el número de la escala de similitud. Mi código es:

```
import ast

for row in data[70:81].itertuples():
    try:
        int(ast.literal_eval(row.Answers)[0]) # ast.literal_eval() because row.Answers is a String # int to test if it's an int
        for i, digit in enumerate(ast.literal_eval(row.Answers)[0]):
            # place the numbers in Answeri
            row['Answer' + str(i)] = digit
    except ValueError:
        print("ValueError")
        pass
```

Pero obtengo:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-235-62669c442f7d> in <module>
      6         for i, digit in enumerate(ast.literal_eval(row.Answers)[0]):
      7             # place the numbers in Answeri
----> 8             row['Answer' + str(i)] = digit
      9     except ValueError:
     10         print("ValueError")

TypeError: 'Pandas' object does not support item assignment
```

He leido que podría hacerlo mucho mejor mediante la vectorización...

## Actualizacion

Intenté hacerlo con lambda funciones:

```
data2 = data.copy()
data2['Answer0'] = data[data.QType=='Likert Scale']['Answer0'].apply(lambda x: '1' if x == '12345' else x)
```

parece que funciona pero cuando intento hacerlo para otras columnas. CUando estoy reescritiendo en la columna que uso para saber si hay un problema en la escala de gustos, no puedo usarlo para las otras columnas.

Answer (score 0):

¡Ya lo tengo! (excepto para los números superiores a 9)

Se necesita transformar desde string, probando si es un grupo anormal o uno normal con la cola. Despues: probar si es un agrupamiento anormal o uno normal con la cola, conseguir el número de título (pero no puede manejar 10s). Luego, obtener número correcto `first + column_name_value` en el lugar correcto.

```
import numpy as np

def to_scale(scale, cell_value, column_name):
    scale = ast.literal_eval(scale) # transform from string
    try:
        if(len(scale) == 1): # testing if it is an abnormally grouped or a normal one
            int(scale[0]) # testing if it is a likert scale as they are lonely bunch of strings
            first = int(scale[0][0])
            last = int(scale[0][-1])
            column_name_value = int(column_name[-1]) # get the title number (but not able to handle 10s)
            if column_name_value <= last:
                place = first + column_name_value
                if place >= first:
                    return place
            else:
                return np.nan
        else: 
            return cell_value
    except ValueError:
        print("ValueError")
        return np.nan

column_names = ['Answer' + str(i) for i in range(0,10)]
for column_name in column_names:
    data2.loc[data2.QType=='Likert Scale',column_name] = data2[data2.QType=='Likert Scale'].apply(lambda x: to_scale(x['Answers'], x[column_name], column_name), axis=1)
```